# Create custom Insert Form

Tags: google-app-maker

I would like to create a Dialog PageFragment that functions exactly as the default Insert Form widget does, except with my own collection of dropdowns and text boxes. It should fill out a ‘draft’ record of the user-inputted data as the user enters it, as explained in the [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/tutorials/work-with-data/#explore_how_the_insert_form_works), then when the user clicks Create/Insert/Submit, the draft is inserted as a new record into a data model, which is displayed as a Table widget. The draft record is then emptied.

I'm sure that I can implement this by calling a server script that create a new item/record in the datasource, but I'm not sure of how exactly to begin implementing that.

Comment: So, you just want to show Create Form in dialog? How would your `textbox` be different from one, that is generated by App Maker?

Comment: It would have a different layout (the Insert Form widget's layout is not as modifiable), contain a Text Editor and multiple Text Boxes and Dropdowns.

Comment: Actually, it is modifiable. You can add/remove widgets from it, change bindings, etc...